# How to fetch the data from multiple tables using pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, spool

I am having the 10 tables for 10 countries. Each table having the two same columns for all countries.

I want to fetch the data from 10 tables at a time and fetched data should saved in text file. i.e each table data should be saved in each text file.

Below is the table description. same for all tables.

```
   Name                                     Null?    Type

MSISDN                                    NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(25)
GREET_FILE_NAME                                      VARCHAR2(100)
```

Kindly help me to make this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `PL/SQL`. Do it in `SQL` using `UNION ALL` and `SPOOL` to get the data from all the 10 tables in a single file. Else, spool in 10 different files for each of the `select` statements.

```
SELECT MSISDN, GREET_FILE_NAME FROM table_1
  UNION ALL
SELECT MSISDN, GREET_FILE_NAME FROM table_2
  UNION ALL
....
 and so on for all 10 tables
  UNION ALL
SELECT MSISDN, GREET_FILE_NAME FROM table_10
```

To avoid duplicates, you can use `UNION`.

To generate a file with your output data, use `SPOOL` command in `SQL*Plus`.

For example,

```
spool <location>
-- your select query here
spool off;
```

You could even wrap it in a `script` file and just execute the script in `SQL*Plus`.

For example,

```
@test.sql
```

That would generate all the table data in a single file.

> i.e each table data should be saved in each text file.

Just execute `SELECT` on each table and `SPOOL` it as shown above. No need of `UNI0N`.

For example,

```
-- file 1
spool text_1.csv
SELECT MSISDN, GREET_FILE_NAME FROM table_1
spool off;

-- file 2
spool text_2.csv
SELECT MSISDN, GREET_FILE_NAME FROM table_2
spool off;
...
and so on for all 10 tables
```